# Find file size using a CRT routine

Tags: c++, windows

So I'm currently using this code to open a specified file:

```
FILE* stream;
stream = fopen("file.txt", "w+");
```

My goal is to get the size of this file but I could not find any explicit function that determined the file size in the CRT runtime library.

I only found `GetFileSize` or `GetFileSizeEx` but these functions are in the `fileapi` header file and use handles instead of streams, meaning I would need to write a big chunk of code just for the file size (opening file, check for validity, get file size using handle, close handle), causing additional overhead.

Any idea of a way I could do it with a CRT routine (such as one that starts by the `f` prefix)?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fstat-fstat32-fstat64-fstati64-fstat32i64-fstat64i32?view=msvc-160

Comment: You can use `stat` with a path if you like. There are examples on both of the linked pages. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stat-functions?view=msvc-160

Comment: For what it's worth, if you plan to open the file in `w+` mode the size will always be 0 since that destroys the contents. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with, however @Remy Lebeau's way works as well.

```
struct _stat fd;
if(_fstat(_fileno(stream), &fd) != 0)
        return -1;
DWORD fsize =  fd.st_size;
```

Answer (score 3):

The typical way to get the size of a  `FILE*` stream is to [`fseek()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fseek-fseeki64?view=msvc-160) to the end of the stream and then [`ftell()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/ftell-ftelli64?view=msvc-160) the position that was actually seeked to.

Note the stream needs to be opened in `"b"`inary mode to disable line break translations that would throw off the position.

```
FILE* stream;
stream = fopen("file.txt", "rb");
fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(stream);
...
```

Comment: Note that this fails for files of size 2GiB and larger. The POSIX-inspired C Standard Library is largely useless when it comes to file I/O. Microsoft's CRT implementation provides mitigations, such as [_ftelli64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/ftell-ftelli64) and [_fseeki64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fseek-fseeki64).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
size_t fileSize(const char* fileName)
{
    ifstream ifs;
    size_t len;

    ifs.open(fileName, ifstream::binary);
    ifs.seekg(0, ios::end);     // go to the end
    len = (size_t)ifs.tellg();  // report length
    ifs.close();
    return len;
}
```

Comment: This can be simplified a bit, by using the `ifstream` constructor to open and seek the stream in a single operation, and letting the destructor close the stream when it goes out of scope, eg: `size_t fileSize(const char* fileName) { return ifstream(fileName, ifstream::binary | ifstream::ate).tellg(); }`

Answer (score 0):

There is good way do it in C++17:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    namespace fs = std::filesystem;
    std::cout << "File size = " << fs::file_size("path_to_file");
    return {};        
}
```

More information here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size